# How to make web browser ignore cookies

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cookies, webbrowser-control, disqus

Im making a windows phone app which uses a WebBrowser.
Im using this web browser to authenticate a users disqus account.
When i boot the emulator and runs the app, the user is requested to input their account/password and all works fine.

Now i want to be able to log in with a different user but the web browser (or disqus, i don't know if it would be the phone or the website that remembers) remembers the user and just gives me the option to accept or reject (meaning I'm not getting the chance to log in like i did the first time).

If i have given you enough information, is there a way to prevent this behavior? Is it because of cookies or the disqus server?

**For others having this problem when implementing the disqus api on windows phone:**
A way past actually trying to delete the cookies through code, a working method is:
Using a WebBrowserControl, navigate to disqus.com/dashboard. The user will be logged in on this site because of the cookie stored on the phone. Then in the LoadComplete event handler add this line:

```
(sender as WebBrowser).InvokeScript("eval", "document.location.href = \"http://disqus.com/logout\";");
```

this will navigate to the logout page of disqus and return a logout cookie (or something, im not sure how this part actually works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't programmatically delete cookies from the Isolated Storage within an App in Windows Phone 7. If you uninstall the app then they are deleted, otherwise they will remain. If the user has disabled cookies in IE then they will not be available, but they are not deleted in this case either.

You could request this feature here: http://wpdev.uservoice.com/

Regards,
Paul

Comment: and there is no way to make the web browser ignore them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's because of the server remembering you, you could try to start a new instance of your webbrowser but you can't manually delete cookie(but you can take a look at them (maybe that helps you)) with for example:

```
Webbrowser test = new Webbrowser();
test.getCookies();
```

Comment: It still happens if i restart the app.